# Finding the volume of a region rotated about the y-axis.

Tags: integration, volume

I'm having trouble trying to find the volume of the region formed by $y = x^2-7x+10$ and $y = x+3$ rotated about the *y-axis*. I was able to graph it, but I'm having difficulty when trying to come up with the integral for it.

Any help showing me how to get the integral I should use would be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

This one may be easier to handle using the *Method of Cylindrical Shells*. Setting $x+3=x^2-7x+10$ we find that the curves meet at $x=1$ and $x=7$.  Over the interval $[1,7]$, the line $y=x+3$ is the upper curve.  When we take a vertical strip of width "$dx$" from $x$ to $x+dx$, and rotate it, we get a cylindrical shell of radius $x$ and height $(x+3)-(x^2-7x+10)=-x^2+8x-7$. Thus the volume is
$$\int_1^7 2\pi x(-x^2+8x-7)\,dx.$$
For the integration, multiply out and integrate term by term.

Comment: that is much tidier!

Comment: Thanks so much, this cleared a lot up! Seems that I was mistaking the y axis with a boundary which skewed a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.  With a clear understanding of the geometry, the rest is often straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

hint: you must split the integration. for $y \in [-\frac94,4]$ the radii of the inner and outer annuli are the two roots of $ x^2-7x+(10-y)=0$, whereas for $y \in [4,10]$ the outer radius is the larger root of that equation, but the inner radius is given by $y-3$